# How to add key-value to object in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I found this expression, but I do not know where is it come from? Where is any documentation for it?

```js
onChange={(
    event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
) => {
    setFormData({ ...formData, [key]: event.target.value })
}}
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What expression is causing confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put any key name here i chose eventValue

```
setFormData({..formData, eventValue: event.target.value})
```

and then you should be able to access it like this

```
function setFormData(formDataObject){
    // access it like this
    formDataObject.eventValue
}
```

Comment: Ok, but where I can read more about this? It is coming with ES6?

Comment: MDN is the best way to go about this: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects